# What to do if we have an array of functions?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array made of function, and i want output of all the function in an array when i put input , I can do it one-by-one using a for loop as we know , but how to do it once if i want the output all at once so that it is fast.

We can regenrate the problem as follows

Suppose we have a square,cube,double and triple function as follows

```
def square(x):
    return x**2

def cube(x):
    return x**3

def double(x):
    return 2*x

def triple(x):
    return 3*x
```

Now create an array of this function, of shape 2x2, as follows

```
arr = np.array([[double , triple],[square , cube]]
```

Now I want to get the an array which gives me its value at 2 , that look something like ```

```
array([[2, 4],
       [6, 8]])
```

While I can do it separately like for double

```
arr[0,0](2)
```

but i want to do all at once efficiently

> Note that this function are just illustrtions, the actual problem have different array made up of different function , but they can take input of same type , that i can say

Comment: *"something like `array([[2, 4], [6, 8]])`"*... did you mean `[[4, 6], [4, 8]]`?

Comment: `arr` is  object dtype.  There isn't a compiled function to do what you want.  An array like this has no advantage compared to a list.

Answer (score 0):

If your array always has the same shape then you could do it like this:

```
arr = np.array([i(2) for i in arr.reshape(4)]).reshape(2,2)
```